# Facebook Javascript SDK: Why do I need a 'app-id' when invoking FB.init()?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5) there is a quickstart of Facebook's javascript SDK. What I don't understand is why there has to be an "app-id" in the parameter. I was just trying to build a share button on my page using javascript SDK, I don't have any facebook app.

Comment: Just leave it out, and see what happens …?

Answer (score 2):

Using an App Id allows Facebook to track and manage usage of the SDK. Anytime you're making a call to the service, they want/need a way to identify where that call is coming from and how it's being used.

Creating an App Id is simple, though. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and click on MyApps at the top. There will be an option in the drop-down to Add a New App. You only need to add a couple pieces of info to get started and an App Id will be generated. You can add more info about your page or site if you want to.

If you just want to add a share button without messing with all that, use the normal Like Button Configurator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: I'd like to do it in the more complicated way, for learning purpose. But I just don't get what a facebook app has to do with my website. This question of mine is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379941/facebook-javascript-sdk-getloginstatus-getting-no-response

Comment: By the way, I did create an app and try everything, but `getLoginStatus(function(response){console.log(1)})`,still encounters problem, it just returns `undefined`, it is like the anonymous function is never executed

Comment: I can't speak to Facebook's reasoning or terminology directly, of course, but I think they're using App Id in a generic way. You're not using it for an app, per se, but it does act as a tracking number for your usage of the SDK and API.

Comment: You might try asking your getLoginStatus question in another question with a code example. I tried to paste a code example here in the comment, but they do not format correctly. It probably has to do with the order and formatting of the status request.

Comment: I did ask, it is here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5

Comment: That's just a link to the developer docs. Post your question (not here) with the code snippet of what you are trying to do. I, or someone else, can probably help you figure out why you're getting `undefined`.